Is it possible to set a timeout property when connecting to a Raspberry Pi using pigpio
Pretty much when you try to connect to a raspberry pi remotely using pigpio, there doesn't seem to be an innate way of setting a timeout property in terms of how long should it attempt to connect to a pi before aborting.
def _connect_to_linked_pi(self):
    try:
        if self.linked_pi is None:
            pi = pigpio.pi(device_ip, PIGPIO_PORT)
            sock = pi.sl.s
            sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
            sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
            sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 1)
            sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error trying to connect -> {e}")


In that code snippet, even if the other end cannot be reached, it will still set up a connection object.
What does happen is it will eventually print out a warning about not being able to reach the pigpio daemon service
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at 192.168.108.1(8888)

Did you start the pigpio daemon? E.g. sudo pigpiod

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the environment
variables PIGPIO_ADDR/PIGPIO_PORT?
E.g. export PIGPIO_ADDR=soft, export PIGPIO_PORT=8888

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the
pigpio.pi() function? E.g. pigpio.pi('soft', 8888)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


But this takes 30 seconds the first time around, and on subsequent attempts this warning takes 3 seconds to appear. Is there a way to just set up a timeout property so as not to be forced to wait for and catch this particular error? THANK YOU!

You can always fall back on using signal.alarm.

Socket level timeouts tend not to be so useful in my experience, they tend to measure the wrong thing and hence I often need something else anyway.

From the pigpio documentation:

An instance attribute connected may be used to check the success of
the connection. If the connection is established successfully
connected will be True, otherwise False.

So you can check pi.connected to see if the connection was successful or not:
pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit()

In my experience, a timeout would not be required because calling pigpio.pi() will return a handle straight away if the connection was successful and return 0 if not (which is another way to check if the connection was successful or not).

As an answer to my own question, what worked best is running the connection function as an async function and setting a timeout property on that async task
try:
    await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(executor, self._reconnect_to_linked_pi), timeout=3)
    print("New connection made!")
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    print("New connection attempt timed out.")

